# How can I parse an relative path to an image inside a React Native Image component source?

Tags: react-native

Given a json object like this

```
 {
    link:"https://www.google.com",
    image:"../../assets/images/googleicon.png",
 },
```

And then this in the component

```
<View>
   {info.image &&
      <Image source={require(info.image)} />
   }
</View>
```

It just yells at me with "Invalid call". If I pass the the path directly it works, like

`<Image source={require('../../assets/images/googleicon.png')} />`

But I can't do that because my view is mapping several images depending on the item viewed. It's not just one item or the same image for all items. It needs to be dynamic. Everything out there points to regular React solutions with HTML. React Native doesn't have HTML as you know